# Default optional parameter in Swift function

Tags: swift, function, option-type

When I set `firstThing` to default `nil` this will work, without the default value of `nil` I get a error that there is a missing parameter when calling the function.

By typing `Int?` I thought it made it optional with a default value of `nil`, am I right? And if so, why doesn't it work without the `= nil`?

```
func test(firstThing: Int? = nil) {
    if firstThing != nil {
        print(firstThing!)
    }
    print("done")
}
test()
```

Comment: Consider that you can write `func test(firstThing: Int = 4)`: a non-`Optional` parameter with a default value. The `Optional` type (which is what `?` in a type name expands to) is a value type; "optional parameter" is an unfortunate name for a parameter that may or may not be present at a function call, regardless of its type.

Comment: What version of Swift have you use to test this code? Your code works fine!! Optional are just a type, and default parameters works fine as with another type in Swift

Answer (score 299, accepted):

Optionals and default parameters are two different things.

An Optional is a variable that can be `nil`, that's it.

Default parameters use a *default* value when you omit that parameter, this default value is specified like this: `func test(param: Int = 0)`

If you specify a parameter that is an optional, you have to provide it, even if the value you want to pass is `nil`. If your function looks like this `func test(param: Int?)`, you can't call it like this `test()`. Even though the parameter is optional, it doesn't have a default value.

You can also combine the two and have a parameter that takes an optional where `nil` is the default value, like this: `func test(param: Int? = nil)`.

Comment: "If you specify a parameter that is an optional, you have to provide it". Great, thanks Swift

Comment: @andrewtweber Your humor is appreciated, but for newbies, I thought it might be helpful to clarify that "Optional" refers to providing an object or value. You don't have to do that, you can provide nil (which represents the absence of an object or value) instead. You just have to decide which option you're choosing.

Answer (score 28):

The default argument allows you to call the function without passing an argument. If you don't pass the argument, then the default argument is supplied. So using your code, this...

```
test()
```

...is exactly the same as this:

```
test(nil)
```

If you leave out the default argument like this...

```
func test(firstThing: Int?) {
    if firstThing != nil {
        print(firstThing!)
    }
    print("done")
}
```

...then you can no longer do this...

```
test()
```

If you do, you will get the "missing argument" error that you described. You must pass an argument every time, even if that argument is just `nil`:

```
test(nil)   // this works
```

Answer (score 25):

Swift is not like languages like JavaScript, where you can call a function without passing the parameters and it will still be called. So to call a function in Swift, you **need** to assign a value to its parameters.

Default values for parameters allow you to assign a value without specifying it when calling the function. That's why `test()` works when you specify a default value on test's declaration.

If you don't include that default value, you need to provide the value on the call: `test(nil)`.

Also, and not directly related to this question, but probably worth to note, you are using the "C++" way of dealing with possibly null pointers, for dealing with possible nil optionals in Swift. The following code is safer (specially in multithreading software), and it allows you to avoid the forced unwrapping of the optional:

```
func test(firstThing: Int? = nil) {
    if let firstThing = firstThing {
        print(firstThing)
    }
    print("done")
}
test()
```

Answer (score 16):

You are conflating `Optional` with having a default. An `Optional` accepts either a value or nil. Having a default permits the argument to be omitted in calling the function. An argument can have a default value with or without being of `Optional` type.

```
func someFunc(param1: String?,
          param2: String = "default value",
          param3: String? = "also has default value") {
    print("param1 = \(param1)")

    print("param2 = \(param2)")

    print("param3 = \(param3)")
}
```

Example calls with output:

```
someFunc(param1: nil, param2: "specific value", param3: "also specific value")

param1 = nil
param2 = specific value
param3 = Optional("also specific value")

someFunc(param1: "has a value")

param1 = Optional("has a value")
param2 = default value
param3 = Optional("also has default value")

someFunc(param1: nil, param3: nil)

param1 = nil
param2 = default value
param3 = nil
```

To summarize:

- Type with ? (e.g. String?) is an `Optional` may be nil or may contain an instance of
  Type
- Argument with default value may be omitted from a call to
  function and the default value will be used
- If both `Optional` and has default, then it may be omitted from function call OR may be included and can be provided with a nil value (e.g. param1: nil)

Comment: can i add default parameter as a variable like let or var? Thanks

Comment: @YogeshPatel Not sure what you mean.

Comment: like var myName = "Yogesh". Now, my function is like 
1. func getFilterNames(name: string = myName){}  this approach is not working for me.
2. func getFilterNames(name: string = "Yogesh"){}  this approach is working for me.
But i want first one so can you please help me to achieve this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @YogeshPatel I think what you may want is `func getFilterNames(name: inout String){ }` which will allow you to modify the name that was passed in.

Comment: No no sir. i don't want to modify my parameter. i just want to give default value to my parameter but not like static "Yogesh". i want to do like let name = "Yogesh" dynamic func getFilterNames(name: string = name) like this. getting this sir ? Thanks!

Comment: @YogeshPatel

'func getFilterNames(name: "Yogesh") -> [String] {
    var name = name;
    //modify name variable'

Answer (score 6):

in case you need to use a bool param, you need just to assign the default value.

```
func test(WithFlag flag: Bool = false){.....}
```

then you can use without or with the param:

```
test() //here flag automatically has the default value: false
test(WithFlag: true) //here flag has the value: true
```

Comment: For people who downvotes this, you can fix the wrong thing instead, so others will understand.

Answer (score 3):

"Optional parameter" means "type of this parameter is optional". It does not mean "This parameter is optional and, therefore, can be ignored when you call the function".

The term "optional parameter" appears to be confusing. To clarify, it's more accurate to say "optional type parameter" instead of "optional parameter" as the word "optional" here is only meant to describe the type of parameter value and nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

## Don't let the question mark fool you!

`Optional` is an `enum` which has two cases:

```
@frozen public enum Optional<Wrapped> : ExpressibleByNilLiteral {

    /// The absence of a value.
    ///
    /// In code, the absence of a value is typically written using the `nil`
    /// literal rather than the explicit `.none` enumeration case.
    case none

    /// The presence of a value, stored as `Wrapped`.
    case some(Wrapped)
}
```

<sub>code from the original compiled source of the Optional inside Xcode</sub>

---

When you are defining a function that accept some `Type` of arguments, you can pass a **default** *value* withe the same type.

#### in your case

the type of the `firstThing` is `Optional<Int>` (also known as `Int?`).  So if you want the caller to the oportunity to ignore the paramter, you **MUST** do the job for the caller and pass a **default value**.

Usually we need the `.none` case of the `optional` so we can do:

```
func test(firstThing: Optional<Int> = .none) { ... }
```

This is exactly the same as:

```
func test(firstThing: Int? = nil) { ... }
```

## Also!

Who seys that we the default value of an optional is a `nil`? maybe passing `nil` means that the function should remove something by updating it's value to 'nil'. So don't asume *"the default value for optional is a nil"*

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to call the `func` with or without the parameter you can create a second `func` of the same name which calls the other.

```
func test(firstThing: Int?) {
    if firstThing != nil {
        print(firstThing!)
    }
    print("done")
}

func test() {
    test(firstThing: nil)
}
```

now you can call a function named `test` without or without the parameter.

```
// both work
test()
test(firstThing: 5)
```

Comment: Why would you define an additional function when you could just specify nil as the default value for the parameter?

Answer (score -1):

It is little tricky when you try to combine optional parameter and default value for that parameter. Like this,

```
func test(param: Int? = nil)
```

These two are completely opposite ideas. When you have an optional type parameter but you also provide default value to it, it is no more an optional type now since it has a default value. Even if the default is nil, swift simply removes the optional binding without checking what the default value is.

So it is always better not to use nil as default value.

Comment: This is incorrect. There's nothing wrong with an optional having a default value (even `nil`).

Comment: what I'm saying is once a variable has a default value, it is not an optional in the sense it will always have a value.

Comment: That's not true, and I'm not sure what you're trying to describe. I think you're correctly saying that once a variable has a value assigned to it, it will always be assigned; you can't unassign it (nor would you want to) unless you deallocate it. And Swift will give you a compilation error if you try to use a variable before it has a value (as in `var foo: String; print(foo)`). But a function argument with a default value is an optional argument (you don't have to pass it in the function call) and it can also be of Optional type (allowing `nil` to be assigned to it, even as the default value).

Comment: An Optional is essentially a union type of < Type | Nil > , ie it can have the Specified type or the Nil Type. (Assuming swift had Unions , which it doesnt, but we're talking conceptually here). so Int? = nil is perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

Default value doesn't mean default value of data type .Here default value mean value defined at the time of defining function.
we have to declare default value of variable while defining variable in function.