# Check if the user pass the value or it used the default optional parameter in Swift function

Tags: swift, swift3

This is not a common case, I want to know if the user passed the value or it used the default value in Swift. For example

```
func test(firstThing: Int? = nil) {
    if firstThing.isNil {
        if // firstThing used the default value {
            print("default")
        } else {
            print("nil ingresed")
        }
     }
}
```

It should have the following behaviour:
    test() // "default"
    test(firstThing: nil) // "nil ingresed"

Comment: You are already assigning the default value to nil, so weather the users passes the value as nil or the compiler uses the default value you will always get the default value

Comment: @OverD Is there a way to check whether the user passed that value or not?

Comment: Have a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37305951/default-optional-parameter-in-swift-function

Comment: I already did it, but it doesn't have the response to my question

Comment: @cibulefc do you consider `nil` a valid input argument? There is no way to check whether the input argument was passed as `nil` or the default value was used, but you can easily check whether it is `nil` or not.

Comment: > do you consider nil a valid input argument? yes.

Comment: Would you mind explain why you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

For this you must write two function with same name. But in one function u set perimeter and in another without perimeter, for example :-

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.myFunc()

        self.myFunc("demo")


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }


    func myFunc()  {
        print("empty")
    }

    func myFunc(_ str : String){
        print(str)
    }

 }
```